# Need a javascript onclick decorator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have legacy code that includes links with hard-coded onclick handlers (bad, I know).

```
<a href="foo" class="linkClass" onclick="someFunc()">link</a>
```

I need to decorate that onclick function.  In other words, I need to to replace the hard-coded onclick function with another function of my own that will first call the original function and then allow me to call my own code.

This is what I've tried, to no avail:

```
 var oldFunc = $('a.linkClass').attr('onclick');
 function newFunc(oldFunc) {
    return function(oldFunc) {
      oldFunc();
      // my add'l code
    }
 }
 $('a.linkClass').attr('onclick', '').unbind('click');
 $('a.linkClass').click(newFunc(oldFunc));
```

Comment: you should use `on` and `off` (not `unbind`), and I'm not sure why you've got a function returning a function (which would be necessary in a loop but not here). Anyway, your issue is that `oldFunc` can only hold a single function, not all of the functions. So you do need a loop to do this.

Comment: Why then negative votes??

Comment: To be clear though, your function returning a function is still wrong, I'll post an answer with the correct code... (also negative voter is likely because you're working around legacy code instead of fixing it. Don't know if it's an option for you, but you should fix it if possible)

Comment: If it were possible, I wouldn't be asking the question and acknowledging that the legacy code is bad.  I still believe there is something instructional in learning how to apply a decorator pattern in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

First issue is need proper selector to find the `onclick` elements. `$('[onclick]')` will find all elements in page with that attribute. Also you need to remove the `onclick` attribute, trying to unbind with jQUery won't work

Assuming each `onclick` only has one function you could try:

```
$('[onclick]').each(function(){
     var $el=$(this)
     var funcName=$el.attr('onclick').replace('()','');
     $el.click(window[funcName]).removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

*Just realizing this won't work if any params in function*

Comment: turning the function into a window-level property is a nice way of getting around using `eval`, but this will fail if the function is being given parameters, or is something more complicated (like `myObject.doThing()`)

Comment: @dave yes...is why i made notation afterwards. Realized after looking at only simplest case

Comment: yeah, there are ways it could be hacked to work like this, but it's not simple code (in the end, you'd be making your own custom javascript interpreter!). Since `onclick` should be trusted code in the first place (it had eval-like behaviour before), I don't think there's any (additional) risk from using `eval` here.

Comment: @Dave good solution by adaneo using window[func] and accessing params

Comment: well, it still fails for `myObject.doThing()` or `doThing(variable)` or `thing1();thing2();` or `myVar=2` (etc.). It's a nice experiment though.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to wrap multiple events, but to do that you need to loop over the elements and wrap each one in turn (javascript can't store multiple functions in a single variable like that!) Also you get a string from `onclick`, so you'll need to `eval` it (which is generally a BadThing (tm). But the real bad thing here is that you're using `onclick` in the first place.

```
var elementsToFix = $('a.linkClass');
for( var i = 0; i < elementsToFix.length; ++ i ) {
    var obj = elementsToFix.eq( i );
    var oldFnc = obj.attr( 'onclick' );
    obj.removeAttr( 'onclick' ).on( 'click', (function( curOldFnc ) {
        return function( ) {
            // pre-wrapper here
            eval( curOldFnc );
            // post-wrapper here
        }
    }( oldFnc )) );
}
```

This uses the super-evil `eval`. That's bad, and the only reason I'm using it is because you get a string from `attr('onclick')` instead of a function. The correct solution is to never use `onclick` in the first place.

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jdn6V/1

Answer (score 0):

As the function called from the onclick handler is in the global scope, the easy solution would be to just remove the onclick handler, store the string, and eval it later.

Of course eval is bad, and there are ways to parse the string, remove the parenthesis and keep any arguments, and call it as `window[oldFunc]` etc. but as a quick example, here it is with eval (which is evil)

```
$('a.linkClass').each(function() {
    var old = $(this).attr('onclick');
    $(this).attr('onclick', '').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        eval.apply(window, [old]);
        alert('new');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jNCxv/)

without eval

```
$('a.linkClass').each(function() {
    var old   = $(this).attr('onclick'),
        func  = old.split('(')[0],
        param = old.split('(')[1].replace(')','').split(',');

    $(this).attr('onclick', '').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window[func].apply(window, param);
        alert('new')
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jNCxv/1/)

Answer (score -1):

`.attr()` always returns a string, so you'd have to eval it to execute the function.

You can get the original function this way, and not need to eval it later:

```
var oldFunc = $('a.linkClass')[0].onclick;
```

(`[0]` picks the "pure" DOM element that has the `onclick` function.)

Now you can bind the function to the element:

```
$('a.linkClass').click( function(e) {
    // new code here
    // ...

    oldFunc(e);
});
```

(`e` given as the parameter, just in case the old function uses it.)

The additional benefit of this is that it works regardless of what's in the old `onclick` attribute because it's wrapped in a function, so e.g. `onclick="foo(); bar(); return false;"` works correctly.

Comment: you run into same problem my solution has...no access to arguments, also need to remove `onclick` attribute

Comment: @charlietfl Not true. All arguments are preserved.

Comment: @charlietfl To be more precise, if you have `onclick="foo('bar');"` then `oldFunc` contains `function() { foo('bar' ); }` (hence "wrapped in a function").

Comment: did find a bug...won't hold context of `this` as param used in markup  http://jsfiddle.net/Gt8HM/5/  Not putting down your solution, just worth knowing